# AsyncTask is using the same thread and queueing all my requests

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, android-thread

In my Android app, I figured out that all my api calls are being queued instead of happening concurrently. I'm assuming they are all being posted to the same thread, while I was under the impression that an `AsyncTask` creates a *new* thread for `doInBackground()`.

```
public class API extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    public interface Listener {
        void completedWithResult(JSONObject result);
    }
    public Listener listener;
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
        if(!canMakeRequest()){
            return internetError().toString();
        }
        String action = strings[0];

        Log.i("API", action +" Sent");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Log.i("API", action +" Received");
        return "";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String json) {
        JSONObject obj;
        obj = new JSONObject(json);
        if(listener != null)listener.completedWithResult(obj);
    }
}
```

In a whole bunch of places in my app I have things like:

```
API api = new API();
api.listener = new API.Listener() {
    @Override
    public void completedWithResult(JSONObject result) {
        Log.i(tag, "Returned with "+result);
    }
};
api.execute("update-address/");
```

And I always create a new instance of `API`, but my logs have all of these calls happening serially and not in parrallel:

```
analytics/log/ Sent
analytics/log/ Returned
get-beta-tester Sent
get-beta-tester Returned
get-following Sent
get-following Returned
get-groups Sent
get-groups Returned
get-follow-requests Sent
get-follow-requests Returned
get-followers Sent
get-followers Returned
analytics/log/ Sent
analytics/log/ Returned
analytics/log/ Sent
analytics/log/ Returned
post-session Sent
post-session Returned
analytics/log/ Sent
analytics/log/ Returned
post-session Sent
post-session Returned
analytics/log/ Sent
analytics/log/ Returned
analytics/log/ Sent
analytics/log/ Returned
unregister-GCM Sent
unregister-GCM Returned
analytics/log/ Sent
analytics/log/ Returned
verify Sent
verify Returned
```

Comment: One of my favorite articles from Mark Murphy dives deep into this here, https://commonsware.com/blog/2012/04/20/asynctask-threading-regression-confirmed.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See here:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

> When first introduced, AsyncTasks were executed serially on a single
>   background thread. Starting with DONUT, this was changed to a pool of
>   threads allowing multiple tasks to operate in parallel. ***Starting with
>   HONEYCOMB, tasks are executed on a single thread*** to avoid common
>   application errors caused by parallel execution.

and the solution is to:

> If you truly want parallel execution, you can invoke
>   executeOnExecutor(java.util.concurrent.Executor, Object[]) with
>   THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR.

```
api.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, "update-address/");
```

Answer (score 1):

Call to `execute` makes AsyncTasks execute on a single background thread serially.

From [AsyncTask's documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html):

> Order of execution
>
> When first introduced, AsyncTasks were executed serially on a single
>   background thread. Starting with DONUT, this was changed to a pool of
>   threads allowing multiple tasks to operate in parallel. Starting with
>   HONEYCOMB, tasks are executed on a single thread to avoid common
>   application errors caused by parallel execution.
>
> If you truly want parallel execution, you can invoke
>   executeOnExecutor(java.util.concurrent.Executor, Object[]) with
>   THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR.

All this mess is one of the reasons I stopped using AsyncTask.

Comment: What do you use instead of AsyncTask?

Comment: @ChaseRoberts I personally use this approach that I call "thread-posters", but I wouldn't go as far as recommending it in general. Many devs use Rx. If you're interested to take a look at my approach you can do it here: https://github.com/techyourchance/thread-poster

Answer (score 0):

Even I wanted to achieve same thing as yours and tried AsyncTask. Later got to know about Executors Thread Pool. I suggest you to go with ThreadPool which will happen concurrently and you can manage threads that are being created.

```
//Sample snapshot
ExecutorService pool = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();//or fixed thread pool

pool.execute(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    //Do your tasks
                }
            });
```

This will help you, [ThreadPoolExecutor](http://%20https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html)